# How to create java.util.Optional<T> object from Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, generics

Java

```
public class MyObject{}
public class MyFactory{
     private Optional<MyObject> myproperty;
     public Optional<MyObject> getMyproperty{...}
     public void setMyproperty{...}
}
```

Spring config xml (doesn't work)

```
<bean id="myproperty" class="java.util.Optional">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>com.MyObject</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="myfactory" class="com.Myfactory">
    <property name="myproperty" ref="myproperty" />
</bean>
```

Does spring support generics beans?

The reason for using Optional is it provide some useful features such as checking value if null. You can complete checking and further action in one line of code.

```
getMyproperty().ifPresent(id -> call.setId(id));
```

Comment: Why do you need an `Optional` of a bean? Presumably it always exists...

Comment: @boris-the-spider I just update the xml

Comment: It doesn't make sense to create `Optional` of anything you would like to inject. You just don't have to create bean and don't require it

Comment: @k0ner thanks, maybe i need to change the design.

Comment: You can use a `factory-method`, but like everyone is saying, why?

Comment: The reason for using Optional<T> is it provide some useful features such as checking value if null. You can complete checking and further action in one line of code.  getMyproperty().ifPresent(id -> call.setId(id))

Comment: If you're injecting `myProperty`, you already know it's not null.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis though it is valid in 99% of real life case, I think we cannot omit that the chance that, the bean he is creating is a pojo that is going to be used in other cases than only being created by the container.

Comment: However, one thing that OP should be aware of is, using `Optional` in parameter may not be a good idea.  http://blog.jhades.org/java-8-how-to-use-optional/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the problem have nothing to do with generics.

You simply need to properly tell Spring to create the bean using a factory method, as `Optional` can only be created though factory methods.  Something like:

```
<bean id="myproperty" class="java.util.Optional" factory-method="of">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Object" value="com.MyObject" />
</bean>
```

for which it is supposed to mean creating the `myproperty` bean by `Optional.of(com.MyObject.class)`  (Change the `factory-method` to `ofNullable` if that's the one you want to use)

Comment: But, as my comment in the question mentioned, it is probably not a very good idea to use Optional in such case

Comment: it might be a little bit strange, but i really like Optional<T> :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use SpEL (**S**pring **E**xpression **L**anguage):

```
<bean id="mybean" ...>
    <property name="optProp" value="#{ T(java.util.Optional).of( @wrapme) }"/>
</bean>
```

Where "wrapme" is the name of a bean defined elsewhere that you want to wrap in `java.util.Optional`.